# How to list all types that implement/extend a particular type in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember using this feature, but can't find it now. After using this action on a type name, it would pop up a window that lists all the types that are subtypes of the type under cursor.

Comment: https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf check this PDF for all shortcuts

Comment: You can use `Shift+Ctrl+A` to search for actions. Typ in `implem` and the action will be listed with the shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

Right Click -> `Go To` -> `Implementations (Ctrl + Alt + B)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this action but it wasn't doing what I supposed it to do. But I was using it in a Kotlin codebase, and it was sending me to the declaration of the superclass under cursor instead of listing the supertypes. Looks like a bug in Kotlin plugin, I should probably file a bug report.

Comment: Here is the bug report (or rather a feature request), in case someone is going to need it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11335